# How to use a variable in ts as a tagname in a HTML file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, replace, string-interpolation

I want to know if there is any way to use the `HTML tag name (<p> for e.g.)` which is obtained from a variable?

The following is the code I tried:

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  name = 'Angular';
  somevalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  tagName;
  getFromCharCode(index) {
    return String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + index);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.tagName = "p";
  }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let x of somevalues; let i = index">
  {{x}} - {{i}}
  {{ getFromCharCode(i) }}
  <h1>{{tagName}}
  </h1>
</div>
```

If I tried like:

```
<{{tagName}}></{{tagName}}>
```

I'm getting error like

> Template parse errors:
>   Unexpected closing tag "{{tagName}}". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265593/angular-how-can-i-use-variable-in-tagname), but I find it is pretty complex for a simple replacement. Is there any other way to achieve this?

EDIT-1:
Many of you suggest to use innerHTML but that would be feasible incase of small contents. In my typical case, I would like to have all my html content in the same file and I would get **only** the name of the tag in `ts` file

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding

Comment: @BlakeMumford, thanks for the dupe but still I am confused, the inner HTML method will work if I have the entire content in the variable. But thats not the case here. I have only the tag name and the content inside tag is hardcoded in HTML file itself.

Comment: You might want to include an example of the HTML that you want to display because I'm finding it difficult to understand what it is that you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **innerHTML** for this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.tagName = "<p></p>";
}

<div [innerHTML]="tagName"></div>
```

Comment: What if I have a lot of content inside `p` tag? I have posted the `p` tag just as an example. But what if I have a `div` and several other tags inside div?

Comment: Not any issue, you can do it using innerHtml

Answer (score 1):

Hi first of all this way will not work as the interpolation considers the value as a string so it will always appear as a text on the screen.

By your question what i understand is you want to add HTML inside an already existing element.

The easiest way way would be: -

in your ts give your variable the value that you want to insert so eg.

```
tagName = `<div> Some text inside </div>`;
```

and then in your html you can simply do:-

```
<h1 [innerHTML]="tagName">
```

other way to do this would be to get the reference of the element in ts and insert it from there

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div *ngFor="let x of somevalues; let i = index">
  {{x}} - {{i}}
  {{ getFromCharCode(i) }}
  <h1 innerHtml="<{{tagName}}></{{tagName}}>"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: almost: `<h1 innerHtml="<' + tagName + '></' + tagName + '>"></h1>`