# Angular - How to use a variable in typescript file as a tagname in a HTML file?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This question is a direct link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074266/how-to-use-a-variable-in-ts-as-a-tagname-in-a-html-file). That question has been marked dupe but in my case, using `innerHTML` would not be a wise choice because the content present as HTML is quite huge.

This is my component's HTML file:

```
<div>
<!-- This ul is the variable value I get from parent -->
    <ul class={{props.wrapperClasses.class}} id={{props.id}}_ul>
        <li class={{props.labelWrapper.direct.class}} >
            <label id={{props.labelProps.direct.id}} for={{props.labelProps.direct.htmlFor}} class={{props.labelProps.direct.class}} ><!-- {...childProps.labelProps.direct} -->
                {{props.labelProps.title}}
            </label>
        </li>
        <li id={{props.contentWrapper.direct.id}} class={{props.contentWrapper.direct.class}}  ><!-- {...childProps.contentWrapper.direct} -->
            <span class={{props.spanWrapper.class}}>
                <input id={{props.id}} #inp/>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

And the corresponding `TS` file:

```
import {Component,OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'inputcomponent',
    templateUrl:"./inputcomponent.html",
    styleUrls:['../app.component.css']
})

export class inputcomponent{
    @ViewChild('inp', { static: false }) inp: ElementRef;
    @Input() props;
    isWrapped = false;
    maxLength ='';
    tagName;
     ngAfterViewInit() {
        Object.assign(this.inp.nativeElement, this.props.content.direct);
     }
    ngOnInit(){
         this.tagName = this.props.tagName;
    }

}
```

As you can see, the `ul` tag is the one I get dynamically. It can be either `ul` or `ol`. If I have to use `innerHTML`, I have to unnecessarily repeat all the internal content. So is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If it was me, I would simply divide into two smaller subcomponents, one for the list and one for list items.  You could avoid repetition with a parent component like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="ordered; else unordered">
  <ol><slot></slot></ol>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #unordered>
  <ul><slot></slot></ul>
</ng-template>
```

then your current component could look something like this.

```html
<dynamic-list [ordered]="someBoolean">
  <!-- ... your <li> items here ... -->
</dynamic-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, Angular templates are compiled at build time and you can't have variable names for tags. You would have to use ngIf to switch between which tags you want to use.